# Ajax POST to save a JSON local file with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

im trying to add data from input to an Actors.json local file. Here's the file structure:

```
[
  {
  "FirstName": "Ricardo",
  "Id": 1,
  "LastName": "Darin"
  },
  {
  "FirstName": "Bruce",
  "Id": 2,
  "LastName": "Willis"
  }
]
```

This is the input:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Id:</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="ID" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>First name:</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="FirstName" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Last name:</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="LastName" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><input type="button" value="ADD" onclick="AddActor()" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

This is my addActor function:

```
function AddActor(){
            $.ajax({
                url: 'save.php',
                method: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: JSON.stringify({'FirstName': $('#FirstName').val(),
                    'Id': $('#ID').val(),
                    'LastName': $('#LastName').val()}),
                success: function () {alert("Thanks!"); },
                error: function() {alert("Error!");}
            });
    }
```

But i don't know what to put inside the save.php file, and try several ways, but no actor is saved.

Comment: try : `data:{Firstname:$("#FirstName").val(), Id : $("#ID").val(), ....}` And on php side, use `$_POST['FirstName'], $_POST['Id']` to get your value.

Comment: while all that stringify stuff? Why not just .serialize() the entire form? And note that `id` in form fields is **NOT** used for submission. You need to have `name` attributes.

Comment: @Marc B Because in his case, this is not a form^^

Comment: @A.Rossi still no need need to stringify the object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add name attribute to your form:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Id:</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="ID" name="ID" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>First name:</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="FirstName" name="FirstName" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Last name:</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="LastName" name="LastName" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><input type="button" value="ADD" onclick="AddActor()" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Change `AddActor()` function:

```
function AddActor(){
        $.ajax({
            url: 'save.php',
            method: 'POST',
            data: $('input').serialize(),
            success: function(result) {alert("Thanks!"); },
            error: function(result) {alert("Error!");}
        });
}
```

`$().serialize` will format all the input fields like a query string (`name=val&name1=val1` format).

In save.php:

```
<?php

    // Adjust the actual location of the file relative 
    // to the location of the PHP script
    $json_str = file_get_contents('Actors.json');

    // Convert json string to PHP array
    $json_arr = json_decode($json_str, true);

    // Make sure this variable is set in case Actors.json is empty
    if(!$json_arr) {
        $json_arr = array();
    }

    // Add new data
    $json_arr[] = $_POST;

    // Encode back to json string and save
    $json_str_done = json_encode($json_arr);
    file_put_contents('Actors.json', $json_str_done);
```

Comment: The OP needs to also add `name` attribute to all their form input fields.

Comment: Oh yeah. Good catch mate!

Comment: Thank you for the answer! But still, no data is saved in the json.

Comment: A chmod on the json file solved the problem, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Forget `JSON.stringify` unless you need it for some other reason. Just use:

```
data: {
    firstName: $('#FirstName').val(),
    lastName: $('#LastName').val(),
    ...
}
```

Each of these will be available as:
`$_POST['firstName']`, `$_POST['lastName']`, etc.

Once you've got those variables, look into [file_put_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) or similar.